# Receive a string as parameter in bash

Tags: bash

I need to make a bash function that receive strings as parameters, assigns it to another variable and prints that variable plus a bunch of others.
I tried this but it doesn't work

File `log.sh`:

```
log() {           
            if [ $# -lt "3" ]
            then
                echo $#
                return -1
            fi    
            CALLER="$1"
            ERRTYPE="$2"
            ERRMSG="$3"
            DATE=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S")
            echo "$CALLER - $ERRTYPE - $ERRMSG - $DATE -$USER"
      }

log $1 $2 $3
```

Call:

```
bash log.sh function WRT "log test 123"
```

Output:

```
funcion - WAR - log - 26/04/2014 - 11:43:44 - USER
```

Comment: Are you sure? Works fine for me.

Comment: not for me. Dont know what the problem is

Comment: I was going to suggest that your script uses DOS line endings, but I think if that were the case your output would have `- USER` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: it doesnt work even if i just print ERRMSG.
i mean: echo "$ERRMSG"

Comment: You quoted the two variables that probably don't matter in the assignment and didn't quote the one that might matter.  In case of doubt, use double quotes.  And consistency is good.  Also, it is better to use `log(){ … }` instead of `function log { … }`.

Comment: doesn't work either. you mean something like this right? 
ERRMSG="$3"

Comment: No word-splitting is performed on the RHS of an assignment; the lack of quotes isn't the problem.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the *exact* command you type and the exact output?

Comment: It is unlikely that `function` was changed to `funcion` or `WRT` to `WAR` by the code you show. Please be precise when you are copying material into a question. Note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around SO is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You've asked 9 questions but accepted 0 answers…

Comment: Also, you did not post the actual call that caused your problem in the original question; had you posted `log $1 $2 $3` in the first place, the solution would have been obvious.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment (now edited into the question) you say:

```
log() {
   if [ $# -lt "3" ]
   then
       echo $#
       return -1
   fi
   CALLER="$1"
   ERRTYPE="$2"
   ERRMSG="$3"
   DATE=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S")
   echo "$CALLER - $ERRTYPE - $ERRMSG - $DATE - $USER"
}

log $1 $2 $3
```

The trouble is that if `$3` contains "`errmsg lala lala`", you pass 5 arguments to `log`, but only print the first three.

You should use:

```
log "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

As I said earlier (in a comment), in case of doubt, use double quotes.